# How to make elements shrink when a user shrinks the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When someone is shrinking the page, my pictures don't shrink with it. How can I make those pictures get smaller as the window gets smaller?

As a beginner, I'm not quite sure what to do here. But I listed some code below and I hope someone can help me.

```
<center>
<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="./krunker.html">
<img src="./krunker.jpg" alt="Krunker.io" height="500" width="1000" />
</a></td>
<td><a href="./bforce.html">
<img src="./bforce.jpeg" alt="Bullet Force" height="500" width="1000" />
</a></td>
</tr>
</center>
```

I was hoping that when I shrink the page, the photos will too, but they won't. What should I do?

Comment: add `max-width: 100%`

Comment: Add a percentage for the width instead of a hard coded width

Comment: FWIW, the [<center>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) tag is obsolete and [text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) should be used instead.

Comment: use relative [units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use CSS. Below is a common set of CSS properties used to make images responsive.

- `max-width: 100%` so the image does not scale beyond its native resolution, i.e. become pixelated. This can be changed to `width: 100%` if you like pixelated images.
- `height: auto` so the image ration is preserved.

**Note:** Do not set `width` or `height` attributes if you do not want the image to be a fixed size.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x400/fc0">
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make those pictures get smaller as the window gets smaller?

Instead of using an 'absolute' unit (500px) you could use a 'relative' unit (for example 30vw).

You could use this CSS to make your images responsive :

```
img {
  width: 30vw;
}
```

See the code here : https://codepen.io/marc-simplon/pen/byPgdQ

You can read that for more information about CSS units: 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp